# How can I prevent the deletion of user profiles in the Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to stop children to delete history from browser. I have only chrome browser. I have implemented following policies to stop incognito or private browsing.

1. AllowDeletingBrowserHistory.(fasle)
2. IncognitoModeAvailability. (1)
3. BrowserGuestModeEnabled.(false)
   The problem is, user can delete history by deleting user profiles(chrome browser profile). After implementing following policies:
4. BrowserAddPersonEnabled. (0)
5. BrowserSignin. (false)
   Now I have only one profile but user can delete the history by deleting the profile.
   Is there any way to disable deleting profile ?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I found for now is to use FocusMe blocker (it's $62.95 for 2 years subscription) to block the application by window title:

After you've installed FocusMe, click "Add a Plan" button, and after several clicks on Next button you'll find Applications window like that on the screenshot, click Add App -> Add your own tab, paste ^Google Chrome$, be sure to select Window Title type. Click Done, and click the box on Regex column near ^Google Chrome$. Next there are different schedule and password settings you can choose from.

[image]

So how that works is basically Chrome always has the name of URL or settings in its title but when you press the settings (manage profiles) button, there is the "Google Chrome" name only, which I used to block.

Comment: Do you know how to get the URL of that window, since it is not visible in the title and the URL field is not showing?

Comment: I don't know whether that window has a URL, probably not as it is a standalone window. How do you want to block it? Did you try the method with FocusMe? Did it work? It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm looking for free solution. I do not like subscriptions.

Comment: What do you mean by "^Google Chrome$ (make regex enabled)"?

Comment: Thx for the update. Since there is a checkbox for regex, this suggests that FocusMe is making a registry entry. This suggests that this can be done manually. Can you identify any such entry, and if so, what is it exactly?